# UIScrollView not scrolling horizontally with dynamic UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, uibutton

I am creating a `customview` which is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. I am adding `UIButtons` inside `UIScrollView` dynamically along with images and actions. But `scrollview` is not scrolling horizontally with buttons. I know this topic is discussed many times on SO. I tried all posts posted on SO, but not getting expected result. Any suggestion about where i am going wrong will be helpful.

MyCustomView.h

```
@interface MyCustomView : UIScrollView

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
+ (id)customView;

@end
```

MyCustomView.m

```
@implementation MyCustomView
@synthesize scrollView;

+ (id)customView
{
    MyCustomView *customView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]  loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];


    if ([customView isKindOfClass:[MyCustomView class]])
        return customView;
    else
        return nil;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self setupHorizontalScrollView];
}

- (void)setupHorizontalScrollView
{
    //scrollView.delegate = self;

    [self.scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:YES];

    scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    //scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    CGFloat cx = 0;
    NSArray *buttons = @[@{@"Tag":@1,@"Image":[UIImage imageNamed:@"borderImage1.png"]},
                         @{@"Tag":@2,@"Image":[UIImage imageNamed:@"borderImage2.png"]},
                         @{@"Tag":@3,@"Image":[UIImage imageNamed:@"borderImage3.png"]},
                         @{@"Tag":@4,@"Image":[UIImage imageNamed:@"borderImage4.png"]},
                         @{@"Tag":@1,@"Image":[UIImage imageNamed:@"borderImage1.png"]},
                         @{@"Tag":@2,@"Image":[UIImage imageNamed:@"borderImage2.png"]},
                         @{@"Tag":@3,@"Image":[UIImage imageNamed:@"borderImage3.png"]},
                         @{@"Tag":@4,@"Image":[UIImage imageNamed:@"borderImage4.png"]},
                         @{@"Tag":@1,@"Image":[UIImage imageNamed:@"borderImage1.png"]}
                         ];

    // CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f);
    for (NSDictionary *dict in buttons)
    {
        UIButton *button =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        CGRect rect = button.frame;
        rect.size.height = 40;
        rect.size.width = 40;
        rect.origin.x = cx;
        rect.origin.y = 0;

        button.frame = rect;
        button.tag = [dict[@"Tag"] integerValue];
        [button setImage:dict[@"Image"]
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      //  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:)
      //   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:button];
        //frame.origin.x+=frame.size.width+20.0f;
        cx += button.frame.size.width+5;
    }

    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(cx, [scrollView bounds].size.height)];
}
@end
```

I went through below SO links, but didn't get solution.

[LINK1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513489/uiscrollview-not-scrolling-programmatically-in-ios-6-7-both) [LINK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472201/issues-with-ios-7-and-scrolling-through-a-uiscrollview-that-contains-uibuttons)[LINK3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819036/ios-uiscrollview-cancel-uibutton-touch-on-scroll) [LINK4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070135/uibutton-doesnt-allow-uiscrollview-to-scroll)

Comment: is that scrollView property another scrollView inside your scrollView or is it an not really needed reference to self?

Comment: print "CX" value and see , What does you get .. If it's greater than scrollview size than it will work other wise not scroll

Answer (score 0):

To be able to scroll you need to keep a view over scrollview that goes out of the bound of the screen. So drag a view and enlarge it beyong the device bounds so that it would be able to hold your subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use UICollectionView for this kind of a problem. It is easier to implement and also will help you do all necessary manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyCustomView` is a subClass of `UIScrollView`. So you don't need to add `UIScrollView` property to your class. Delete `scrollView` property and replace all `self.scrollView` with `self`